# Insert the Column Name of the Column with the Highest Value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I have the following table in MySQL:

```
user_id  column1  column2  column3  column4  column5
-------  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------
1        1        15       12       20       25
2        5        9        6        15       10
3        7        12       21       9        17
```

And I want to insert the user_id as well as the column name with the highest value for each record into a new table, like the following:

```
user_id  highest_val
-------  -----------
1        column5
2        column4
3        column3
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

So far I've managed to only get the value of the column using the following query but not the column name itself:

```
insert into table2 (user_id, highest_val) SELECT user_id, GREATEST(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5) FROM table1
```

Comment: If you have control over this table structure, change it. This is going to cause you headaches.

Comment: Hint: Use a `CASE` expression along with the `GREATEST()` function.

Comment: @Barmar That gives a value from the field, right? OP wants the column name.

Comment: what if theres a tie how do you determine which column to select

Comment: @dfundako `CASE GREATEST(...) WHEN column1 THEN 'column1' WHEN column2 THEN 'column2' ... END`

Comment: @Barmar Got it. Hence my comment about changing the structure. This will become unmanageable with more columns.

Comment: @dfundako Hence my upvoting your comment. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming no values are `NULL`, you can use a `case` expression:

```
select t.*,
       (case when column1 = greatest(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5) then 'column1'
             when column2 = greatest(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5) then 'column2'
             when column3 = greatest(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5) then 'column3'
             when column4 = greatest(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5) then 'column4'
             when column5 = greatest(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5) then 'column5'
      end) as greatest_column             
from t;
```

You can also phrase this as:

```
select t.*,
       (case greatest(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5)
             when column1 then 'column1'
             when column2 then 'column2'
             when column3 then 'column3'
             when column4 then 'column4'
             when column5 then 'column5'
      end) as greatest_column             
from t;
```

Answer (score 2):

use a `CASE` expression to get the corresponding column name.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (user_id, highest_val)
SELECT user_id,
    CASE GREATEST(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5)
        WHEN column1 THEN 'column1'
        WHEN column2 THEN 'column2'
        WHEN column3 THEN 'column3'
        WHEN column4 THEN 'column4'
        ELSE 'column5'
    END AS highest_val
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a CTE along with union like below:

```
with cte as (select user_id, column1 as col, 1 [group] 
from #temp
union all
select user_id, column2, 2 [group]
from #temp
union all
select user_id, column3, 3 [group]
from #temp
union all
select user_id, column4, 4 [group]
from #temp
union all
select user_id, column5, 5 [group]
from #temp) 


select a.user_id, 'column'+cast([group] as varchar(max)) highest_val from cte a join
(select user_id, max(col) col from cte
group by user_id )b
on a.user_id=b.user_id and a.col=b.col
```